# Как сделать русские названия классов в Django-admin?

Tags: python, django-admin

Как переименовать *entry* в *запись*, а *Blog* в *блог* (`blog` - название приложения)?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ....
    ....
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u"Запись"
        verbose_name_plural = u"Записи"
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/

Comment: А чтобы перевести название аппа (Blog), надо настроить переводы: сгенерировать po и mo файлы. Если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Спасибо, с моделями разобрался, теперь вопрос в том, как переименовать blog в блог, [эта штука](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/options/#app-label) не сработала.

Comment: Как вариант, копируешь шаблон с админки admin/app_index.html в папку с шаблонами с таким же путем. В нем ищешь: {% load ....%}. В этот блок добавляешь i18n, если его нету. Далее ищешь {{ app.name }} и заменяешь на {% trans app.name %}.

Далее, пишешь в консоле: python manage.py makemessages -all (прежде настрой пути для переводов). В сгенерированных файлах переводишь название аппов. Далее пишешь: python manage.py compilemessages. Ребут сервера и все.

Comment: Хотя, вот смотрю в последней ветке джанги - с шаблонами все уже сделано. Скомпилируй переводы и переведи.

Comment: Ок, спасибо...